# Implicit Missing Values in Time Series for Data Imputation

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data

I have multiple time series data over 14 days. Each day should contain 6 data entries (i.e. signals). Each signal is coded (from 1 to 6) over a day, however there are sometimes missing signals - sometimes even that much that for one whole day no data entry is available.
My problems are (1) detect when a whole day is missing 
(2) Insert for each missing Signal an emppty row, but with counted Signals. (Imagine the time series has more than two variables).
I tried a lot but did not come up with a solution.

For example, suppose my time series looks like this:

```
    problem = data.frame(Date = c("2019-11-28 19:45:51 CET", "2019-11-28 22:13:40 CET", "2019-11-29 09:28:41 CET", "2019-11-29 11:40:08 CET",
"2019-11-29 14:01:12 CET", "2019-11-29 16:41:59 CET", "2019-11-29 19:43:15 CET", "2019-11-29 21:36:33 CET",
"2019-11-30 09:45:32 CET", "2019-11-30 11:46:51 CET", "2019-11-30 14:16:35 CET", "2019-11-30 16:43:57 CET",
"2019-11-30 22:06:34 CET", "2019-12-01 09:36:35 CET", "2019-12-01 11:46:41 CET", "2019-12-01 14:02:20 CET",
"2019-12-01 17:02:55 CET", "2019-12-01 19:03:15 CET", "2019-12-01 21:39:51 CET", "2019-12-03 09:24:03 CET",
"2019-12-03 12:09:05 CET", "2019-12-03 14:43:10 CET", "2019-12-03 16:34:00 CET"), 
Signal = c(5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4))
```

In this example some single Signals are missing, but als a whole day (2019-12-02). 
I would expect the follwoing:

```
 expected = data.frame(Date = c(NA, NA, NA, "2019-11-28 19:45:51 CET", "2019-11-28 22:13:40 CET", "2019-11-29 09:28:41 CET", "2019-11-29 11:40:08 CET",
                        "2019-11-29 14:01:12 CET", "2019-11-29 16:41:59 CET", "2019-11-29 19:43:15 CET", "2019-11-29 21:36:33 CET",
                        "2019-11-30 09:45:32 CET", "2019-11-30 11:46:51 CET", "2019-11-30 14:16:35 CET", "2019-11-30 16:43:57 CET", NA, 
                        "2019-11-30 22:06:34 CET", "2019-12-01 09:36:35 CET", "2019-12-01 11:46:41 CET", "2019-12-01 14:02:20 CET",
                        "2019-12-01 17:02:55 CET", "2019-12-01 19:03:15 CET", "2019-12-01 21:39:51 CET", "2019-12-03 09:24:03 CET", NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                        "2019-12-03 12:09:05 CET", "2019-12-03 14:43:10 CET", "2019-12-03 16:34:00 CET", NA, NA,NA),
               Signal = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Comment: I used the package: imputeTS works really well. There are few functions to help with this if you have already converted the data into ts (time series). For example: statsNA give you a statistical overview of your NAs (assumption is that you converted the missing data into NA not zeros). Another great function in this package is plotNA.gapsize which gives you an overview of where and what their distribution are. And the na_interpolation gives you a good method for imputation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Beyond imputeTS (which is mostly useful of you want to interpolate the NAs) there is also the package 'tsibble', which can insert implicit missing values back into your time series. It has a function fill_na to turn implicit missing values into explicit missing values. But it does this according to your time series (assuming it is equally spaced). I don't think it will help you here since your case is quite specific - probably you have to just program it on your own.